# How to add style property to react-sidenav

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to implement [react-sidenav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sidenav), and I would like the buttons to be at the bottom - a flex-direcion of column-reverse. I can add these styles manually in chrome, and it works. According to the documentation, there is a style property on SideNav that I can use to set my custom style. I would change it from block to flex and add the column-reverse flex direction.

I cannot get the style property to work, however. I have tried this:

```
const SideNavBottom = {'display': 'flex', 'flex-direction': 'column-reverse'};
.
.
<SideNav
  style={SideNavBottom}
>
```

You can view a demo of what I am working with at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zmjr5vy76). You will want to look at the RenderItems2 file.

Answer (score 0):

```
const SideNavBottom = {display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column-reverse'};

<SideNav
  style={SideNavBottom}
/>
```

or

```
<SideNav
  style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column-reverse'}}
/>
```

your sidenav component not closed, also you can test above code

Comment: Doesn't work. It's not closed because it was just the top part of the tag. You can see it in the sandbox link I sent you.